# How to create SEO 301 redirections when moving Magento to a subdomain

Tags: migration, subdomain

As I asked it in the title, I decided to move my Magento Store to a subdomain.
I created a showcase site that is published at my main domain.

The thing is my store was published for 2 years and even if I didn't work on SEO improvments, my website was listed and my URLs were crawled by Google.

I was wondering if it was existing a template/a way to redirect all the previous URL of my store in the subdomain.

Is it a good practice to do it or doesn't it matter ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think your Magento store has a large number of products, and categories, so your Magento store has many URLs that do not follow any rules, eg:

Product URLs:

- domain.com/table-a.html
- domain.com/short-pant-a.com
- ...

So you should redirect all URLs from the main website to the subdomain but also skip redirect the main website's URLs.

Try the following config for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    set $WEB_ROOT /path/to/mainwebsite/root;
    ...

    # Redirect all URLs to subdomain 
    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    # Keep the below URLs stay in the main website
    location ~/(url-part-1|url-part-2|url-part-3) {
        root $WEB_ROOT;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mention that I use Nginx and not Apache ; but anyway I know how to create redirections, I just want to know if there is an exhaustive list of redirects to do ; and I'm still using the main domain for my showcase website so I don't want to redirect all the requests to the subdomain

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.